# next() is not a function unable to use generators in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am using the following code in NodeJS 7.10.0:

```
function * gen(){
    yield 100;
    yield 200;
    yield 300
}
console.log(gen.next());
```

and I get this in return:

```
TypeError: gen.next is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Files/development/learning/node-bits/generators.js:15:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:151:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:542:3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call a generator function, its body is not executed. Instead it returns you an iterator object. When you call `iterator.next()`, body is executed, you get the value and context is maintained.

You can do

```
let i= gen()
console.log(i.next())
```

and you will get the desired behaviour.

Refer this: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

Comment: Thanks for that, sounds obvious when I read your post - maybe another time my brain will kick in. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should assign the output of `gen` to a variable and call `next` on the returned value:

```
const out = gen();
console.log(out.next());
console.log(out.next());
console.log(out.next());
console.log(out.next());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but krrish had a better explanation.